# Spring JUnit Testing: Autowiring and Transaction Problems

Tags: spring, junit, autowired

We have an existing Java EE application that leverages Spring and are transitioning from xml configuration to autowiring.  We just converted most of our EJBs to Spring beans, but currently still use MDBs and EJB timers.

- WAS 7.0
- Java 6
- Spring 3.0.5
- JUnit 4.8.1

I am also in the process of writing integration tests in JUnit.  My integration tests use most of the context configuration files as when running in WAS, but not things that tie into JNDI or use the JTA transaction manager.  For those, I have equivalents that setup ActiveMQ queues, a Hibernate transaction manager, etc.

My test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/junit-container-context.xml",
    "/spring-contexts/service-context.xml",
    "/spring-contexts/integration-context.xml",
    "/available-tests-context.xml" })
public class TestCase1Runner {

    @Autowired
    TestCase1 test;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setupErrorHandling() {
        // Some setup
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void run() throws Exception {
        test.executeTest();
    }
}
```

My tests are having problems for at least a couple of reasons:

1. Autowiring skips some beans
2. Sometimes beans are not proxied for transactions

Item 1 seems to have something to do with circular references.  I made copies of some of the beans that had autowiring problems.  I made the copies in the same package.  The copy gets wired up, but not the original.  I then began to move references in the xml context files from the original to the copy, and at some point, the copy no longer gets wired but the original does.  I have the following in one of the context files (with the names changed to protect me :):

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.mycompany.package1,com.mycompany.package2" />

<context:annotation-config />
```

I think the second entity is redundant, but should be innocuous.

I don't see any errors in the logs.  I turned logging to debug and see most of the beans being autowired, but no errors on those Spring seems to skip.

Item 2 might be related to Item 1.  Some beans are not properly proxied to handle transactions.  In my JUnit-only context, I have the following:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut"
        expression="execution(public * com.mycompany.package1..*.*(..))" />

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" />
</aop:config>
```

I am getting hibernate errors in some places because there is no transaction, while in other places, the beans are proxied and transactions are started.  Both the proxied and non-proxied beans are in subpackages of `com.mycompany.package1`.

Of course, all of this works when we run the application in WAS.  It uses a ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.  I tried that as well in JUnit, but it has not seemed to help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your test class should extend from:

```
AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
```

and then you can configure the transactional stuff with:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
```

where defaultRollback defines whether to rollback after every test.

Comment: I actually found the issue.  I had a PropertyOverrideConfigurer in the mix.  The beans that matched the override were the beans that where not proxied.  So I commented out the values in the override file and that made everything work as expected.